# How do I concatenate values from 2 fields into one field

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm trying to concatenate 2 fields (Name and Other names) into one variable. For example, if my name is *Jeffrey* and other name is *Johnston* the the result should be *Jeffrey Johnston*.

I have tried the following on *PRE-TEXT-ITEM*

```
BEGIN 
    :LOAN.NAME := ':LOAN.NAME :LOAN.OTHER_NAMES';
END;

BEGIN 
    :LOAN.NAME := :LOAN.NAME + ' ' + :LOAN.OTHER_NAMES;
END;
```

When trying the following code

```
BEGIN 
    :LOAN.NAME := :LOAN.NAME + ' ' + :LOAN.OTHER_NAMES;
END;
```

I received this error message:

> FRM-40735: PRE-TEXT-ITEM trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-06502

Comment: The Oracle symbol for the concatenation operator is `||` (two pipe symbols), not `+`. That should be pretty much all you need.

Comment: @mathguy thanks! This works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `||`

```
BEGIN 
    :LOAN.NAME := :LOAN.NAME || ' ' || :LOAN.OTHER_NAMES;
END;
```